# Android 4.0.x hangs or reboots on drop of an item within the same ListView

Tags: drag-and-drop, android-listview

### Purpose

I have implemented the "reorder items from a ListView" paradigm following the Android 3.0 Drag & drop framework.

### Issue

Seen on android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4. Not tested on other releases.

Drag an item of the ListView and drop it after the last item of the ListView.
The shadow box is cleared and the ListView invalidated. That is the nominal behaviour and happens 90% of the time.

But for the remaining 10%, what happens is:

- **NB**: all of the effects listed below are seen AFTER `onDrag(View, DragEvent)` has returned for `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED`, that is to say the entire drag & drop process seems to be completed before the problems occur.
- the shadow box is displayed for a mere 10 seconds before disappearance. Calling `view.invalidate()` in `onDrag(View, DragEvent)` handler for `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` will correct that but won't fix the hang or reboot problem (see below)
- some unusual traces in logcat:

> I/ViewRootImpl(  954): Reporting drop result: true I/InputQueue-JNI( 
>   210): Sending finished signal for input channel 'drag (client)' since
>   it is being unregistered while an input message is still in progress.
>   I/InputQueue-JNI(  210): Ignoring finish signal on channel that is no
>   longer registered. W/WindowManager(  210): Drag is in progress but
>   there is no drag window handle. I/ViewRootImpl(  954): Reporting drop
>   result: true

- on some device, Android hangs or reboots. It depends of the device but the effect is always the same.

### Source code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TestReorderActivity extends ListActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = getListView();
        String[] listeStrings = { "France", "United States", "Russia" };
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listeStrings));

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
                    int id, long position) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText(" ",
                        Long.toString(position));

                DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(
                        view);
                if (view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder/*
                                                     * new
                                                     * MyDragShadowBuilder(view)
                                                     */, view, 0)) {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

        listView.setOnDragListener(new ListView.OnDragListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
                final int action = event.getAction();

                switch (action) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                    if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(
                            ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                        // accept drag
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        // reject drag
                        return false;
                    }

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    // entered drag
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                    // location is returned as event.getX() and event.getY()
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    // cancel drag.
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // item dropped
                    processDrop(event);
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                default: // unknown case
                    return true;
                }
            }

            private boolean processDrop(DragEvent event) {
                ClipData data = event.getClipData();
                if ((data != null) && (data.getItemCount() > 0)) {
                    ClipData.Item item = data.getItemAt(0);
                    CharSequence value = item.getText();
                    long position = Long.valueOf(value.toString());

                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();

                    ListView listView = getListView();

                    int newPosition = listView.pointToPosition(x, y);
                    if (newPosition > ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {

                        swap(position, newPosition);
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }

        });

    }

    // swap(long, long) here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is that: your screen upload action_move too lazily.

in normal case , action move is uploading very frequently even if your finger don't move on the screen. but some phone screens are not so sensitive.

you can modify the threshold of your  phone. It needs kernel support.

Answer (score 0):

this is because : unregisterInputChannel fail to get the lock, dead lock occur.